# Modeling a complex number, I am missing a main method when I create my class. Can someone guide me on how to fix it?

Tags: java

> Your task is to create a class that will model a complex number.
>
> A complex number is a number of the form a + bi, where a is the “real”
>   part and b is the “imaginary” part.  It is based on the mathematical
>   premise that i2 = -1.  So like the fraction class, you will define two
>   double data members for real and imaginary.

I will be pulling from a driver file that my professor has supplied to us. I am having no issues compiling, however am having issues running my program. I am getting a popup window from JGrasp that states "No Main methods, Java FX applications, applets, or midlets found in file.". I'm assuming that I need to put a main method into my created class however I am not sure where to put it or how to label/define it. Can someone guide me to solve this?

Thank you, my code is below.

```java
class Complex {

   private double real;

   private double imaginary;

   final double LIMIT = 10;// final means that this object stays the same for all.

   Complex() {//constructors (there are 3, progressing in size)

      real = 0;
      imaginary = 0;
   }

   Complex(double actual) {// parameter calls what I'm assigning real to

      this.real = actual;
      imaginary = 0;

   }

   Complex(double actual, double fake) {

      this.real = actual;
      this.imaginary = fake;

   }

   public double getReal() {//accessors (there are 2, one for each parameter)

      return real;

   }

   public double getImaginary() {

      return imaginary;

   }

   public void setReal(double actual) {// sets real to actual, mutator.

      this.real = actual;

   }

   public void setImaginary(double fake) {// sets imaginary to fake, mutator.

      this.imaginary = fake;

   }

   public String toString() {//returns a String neatly in the form a + bi

      return real + " " + imaginary + "i";

   }

   public boolean equals(Complex complexNumber) {

      if(real == complexNumber.real && imaginary == complexNumber.imaginary) {//takes a complex number as a parameter type and 
      //returns a boolean of true if the calling object is equal to the parameter.

         return true;

      }

      else {

         return false;

      }
   }   

      public Complex add(Complex complexNumber) {

         Complex temp = new Complex (0.0,0.0);

         temp.real = real + complexNumber.real;

         temp.imaginary = imaginary + complexNumber.imaginary;

         return temp;

      }

      public Complex add (double val) {

         Complex temp = new Complex(0.0, 0.0);

         temp.real = real + val;

         temp.imaginary = imaginary + val;


         return temp;

      }



// Override method to add fist parameter Complex object value with second Complex parameter object value

         public static Complex add(Complex complexNumber, Complex c2) {

            Complex temp = new Complex(0.0, 0.0);

            temp.real = complexNumber.real + c2.real;

            temp.imaginary = complexNumber.imaginary + c2.imaginary;

            return temp;

         }// End of method



// Method to check the size of implicit Complex object is greater than the LIMIT

// If greater than return true

// Otherwise return false

         public boolean isBig() {

// Calculates size

            double size = Math.sqrt((Math.pow(real, 2) + Math.pow(imaginary, 2)));

// Checks if size is greater than LIMIT return true

            if(size > LIMIT)

               return true;

// Otherwise not big return false

            else

               return false;

         }// End of method


   }   // End of class
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not put the main method of the application in this class, but a separate one, e.g. App, in the same package or higher in the package hierarchy, with a body like

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(new Complex(0.1, 0.2));
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a separate driver file already, saved in a separate location.

class ComplexTester {
   public static void main(String args[] ) {
   
   //create complex numbers testing all three constructors
   Complex one = new Complex();
   Complex two = new Complex(5);
   Complex three = new Complex(2.1,3.5);
...

Comment: then you probably need to save that file in the same location and run it.